# Map formula to IEnumerable bycode

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to use a formula to map a property of type ICollection however, no matter which method I use to determine the type within the mapping nHibernate throws an error.

`No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

Here is the mapping file

```
this.Property(
  x => x.AllChildIds,
  m =>
    {
      m.Type<NHibernate.Type.ListType>();
      m.Access(Accessor.Field);
      m.Formula(@"(WITH [Child] ([Id], [ParentId])
           AS (SELECT [hs0].[Id],
                      [hs0].[ParentId]
               FROM   [Client].[dbo].[HierarchySet] [hs0] (NOLOCK)
               WHERE  [hs0].[ParentId] IN (SELECT [hs1].[Id]
                                     FROM   [Client].[dbo].[HierarchySet] [hs1] (NOLOCK)
                                     WHERE  [hs1].[Id] = Id /* @p0 */)
               UNION ALL


               SELECT [Children].[Id],
                      [Children].[ParentId]
               FROM   [Client].[dbo].[HierarchySet](NOLOCK) AS [Children]
                      JOIN [Child]
                        ON [Children].[ParentId] = [Child].[Id])


      SELECT [Child].[Id]
      FROM   [Child]
      )");
});
```

And here is my class

```
private readonly ICollection<long> allChildIds;
public virtual IEnumerable<long> AllChildIds { get { return this.allChildIds; } }
```

If I change the type in the mapping file to

`m.Type<NHibernate.Type.GenericListType<NHibernate.Type.Int64Type>>();`

Then I get an `Could not determine type for: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable` error

I know the SQL is complex but surely that shouldn't affect it?

**Edit** My NHibernate session configuration

```
private static Configuration ConfigureNHibernate()
{
  var configration = new Configuration();

  configration.SessionFactoryName("SessionFactoryName");
  configration.DataBaseIntegration(db =>
                                     {
                                       db.Dialect<MsSql2005Dialect>();
                                       db.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();

                                       db.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted;
                                       db.ConnectionStringName = "database";
                                       db.BatchSize = 20;
                                       db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.AutoQuote;
                                     });

  if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["nhibernate-cache"] != null)
  {
    configration.Cache(
                       x =>
                         {
                           x.DefaultExpiration = 300;
                           x.UseMinimalPuts = true;
                           x.RegionsPrefix = "client-";
                           x.Provider<SysCacheProvider>();
                           x.UseQueryCache = true;
                         });
  }

  var mapper = new ModelMapper();
  mapper.AddMappings(typeof(MessageInMap).Assembly.GetTypes());
  var domainMapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();

  configration.AddMapping(domainMapping);

    configration.AddAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(new SimpleAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(@"
                            CREATE VIEW [Children]
                            AS 
                            WITH [Child] ([Id], [ParentId])
                            AS (
                                    SELECT 
                                            [hs0].[Id],
                                            [hs0].[ParentId]
                                    FROM   
                                            [isnapshot.Client].[dbo].[HierarchySet] (NOLOCK) AS [hs0]

                                    UNION ALL

                                    SELECT 
                                            [Children_].[Id],
                                            [Children_].[ParentId]
                                    FROM   
                                            [isnapshot.Client].[dbo].[HierarchySet] (NOLOCK) AS [Children_]
                                    JOIN [Child] ON [Children_].[ParentId] = [Child].[Id]
                            )
                            GO", "DROP VIEW [Children]"));

  return configration;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you omit the type specification? According to the [documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property), this should be fine: "If you do not specify a type, NHibernate will use reflection upon the named property to take a guess at the correct NHibernate type."

Comment: If I don't specify the type the error changes to ICollection `Could not determine type for: System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`

Comment: OK, that's unfortunate. Have you tried ruling out that the query is part of the problem? Does it work for substantially easier queries (either with the same or a different result type)

Comment: Unfortunately, trying a simple select gives the same result

Comment: Well, you call that unfortunate but having narrowed down the problem cause (i.e., ruled out a possible cause) substantially helps people understand/reproduce the problem. Could you thus try to post the most simple form of the problem you can find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map it as set (bag, list, etc) of components, not as property. Then use sub-select to fetch it.

My first assumption is to map it as following

```
c.Set(m => m.ChildrenIds,
    x =>
        {
            x.Access(Accessor.Field);
            x.Key(k => k.Column("ParentId"));
            x.Subselect(@"WITH [Child] ([Id], [ParentId])
AS 
(
    SELECT 
        [hs0].[Id],
        [hs0].[ParentId]
    FROM   
        [HierarchySet] (NOLOCK) AS [hs0]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        [Children].[Id],
        [Children].[ParentId]
    FROM   
        [HierarchySet] (NOLOCK) AS [Children]
    JOIN 
        [Child] ON [Children].[ParentId] = [Child].[Id]
)

SELECT *
FROM [Child]");
        },
    x => x.Element(e => e.Column("Id")));
```

However it does not work, as `WITH` clause does not want to be inside subselect. The generated query:

```
SELECT 
    childrenid0_.ParentId as ParentId0_, 
    childrenid0_.Id as Id0_ 
FROM ( WITH [Child] ([Id], [ParentId])
AS 
(
    SELECT 
        [hs0].[Id],
        [hs0].[ParentId]
    FROM   
        [HierarchySet] (NOLOCK) AS [hs0]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        [Children].[Id],
        [Children].[ParentId]
    FROM   
        [HierarchySet] (NOLOCK) AS [Children]
    JOIN 
        [Child] ON [Children].[ParentId] = [Child].[Id]
)

SELECT *
FROM [Child] ) childrenid0_ 
WHERE childrenid0_.ParentId=@p0;@p0 = 2 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

So in this case the only solution - create a view, and map to it.

Add the database object to configuration

```
configuration.AddAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(new SimpleAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(@"
    CREATE VIEW [Children]
    AS 
    WITH [Child] ([Id], [ParentId])
    AS (
        SELECT 
            [hs0].[Id],
            [hs0].[ParentId]
        FROM   
            [HierarchySet] (NOLOCK) AS [hs0]

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            [Children].[Id],
            [Children].[ParentId]
        FROM   
            [HierarchySet] (NOLOCK) AS [Children]
        JOIN [Child] ON [Children].[ParentId] = [Child].[Id]
    )

    SELECT *
    FROM [Child]", "DROP VIEW [Children]"));
```

If you are using SchemaExport/SchemaUpdate features to create/update your database schema - NHibernate will create the view. **If you are not using SchemaExport/SchemaUpdate features then you need to create the view manually.**

```
CREATE VIEW [Children]
AS 
    WITH [Child] ([Id], [ParentId])
    AS (
        SELECT 
            [hs0].[Id],
            [hs0].[ParentId]
        FROM   
            [HierarchySet] (NOLOCK) AS [hs0]

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            [Children].[Id],
            [Children].[ParentId]
        FROM   
            [HierarchySet] (NOLOCK) AS [Children]
        JOIN [Child] ON [Children].[ParentId] = [Child].[Id]
    )

    SELECT *
    FROM   [Child]
```

The mapping:

```
c.Set(m => m.ChildrenIds,
    x =>
        {
            x.Access(Accessor.Field);
            x.Key(k => k.Column("ParentId"));
            x.Table("Children"); // or x.Subselect("select * from Children") 
        },
    x => x.Element(e => e.Column("Id")));
```

Comment: This seems like a valid solution however when retrieving the results it's having difficulty finding the view. I've tried specifying the schema in the mapping and also prefixed the create view with the database name. When I try to access the field it says failed to initialize collection, `"Invalid object name 'Children'."` Where exactly is the view created?

Comment: Very strange, as it works fine for me:( In my case the view is creating under <mydb>.dbo. schema.

Comment: Can you try to replace `x.Table("Children")` with `x.Subselect("select * from Children")` ?

Comment: Same result, it's as if the view is being delete before it gets chance to read from it. Either that or it's not being created at all. So I removed the drop statement from the auxiliary object creation, which didn't work either. If I create the view manually in SSMS it works, however I can only assume that the data will not update as the main tables do

Comment: I've added the session configuration just in case you can see anything which may cause an issue

Comment: @JLevett AuxiliaryDatabaseObject works only when you are using SchemaExport/SchemaUpdate feature, if you are not creating/updating db schema with NHibernate - then you need to create this view manually.

Comment: The data in view is always up-to-date

Comment: Ahh ok, I misread that at first. Working perfectly now, thank you very much